# How to access json data file for all svelte components in sapper/polka

Tags: javascript, json, express, svelte

I'm trying to rewrite my website(Pug+Express) in Sapper(sveltejs). I'm a beginner in sveltejs , so kindly excuse if my question may come out really naive. 
I have a template.json file that contains all the static data of my website. In the expressjs version I do `const template = require('template.json')` and render the page using pug template something like this

```
router.get('/:pageName', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('pages/About', {template: template})
```

What would be an equivalent version of achieving this in sveltejs/sapper?
So far I did an `import template from 'template.json'` in `app/server.js` file.
Then what? Since the [sapper-template](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template) is using polka instead of express, I'm confused how to get it right.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd put that data in the pages (i.e. components in `routes`) that use it:

```html
<!-- routes/index.html -->
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<script>
  import data from './_template.json';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        title: data.title
      };
    }
  };
</script>
```

Note that I've added an underscore to `_template.json`, to hide the file from the router — you could also just place the JSON file outside the `routes` directory.

You can use Express instead of Polka; just `npm install express` and replace every occurrence of `polka` in `app/server.js` with `express`.

Comment: Super! Worked like a charm.

Comment: This is client side. It doesn't look very safe for sensitive data.